# Anaconda can't find the module

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, pyautogui

Anaconda: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui' However, I can import the module in the terminal on my Mac. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Anaconda Environment is exactly the environment that you test with Terminal before.

If not, create your own Anaconda Environment for Spyder

```
conda create -n spyderenv python=3.5
```

then choose `spyderenv` in spyder